# View js, listener for v-text-field without freeze ui

Tags: vue.js

I have v-text-field

```html
<v-text-field
  name="name"
  label="B/F/L Cost"
  prefix="$"
  @input="throttledSave"
  v-model="$store.state.campaign.MyCost"
></v-text-field>
```

```js
methods: {
  save(val) {
    console.log(val);
  },

  throttledSave(val) {
    let DELAY = 5000;
    return this.throttle(this.save(val), DELAY);
  },

  throttle(callback, limit) {
    console.log("throttle");
    var wait = false;
    return function() {
      if (!wait) {
        console.log("throttle");
        callback.call();
        wait = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
          wait = false;
        }, limit);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I need to add listener for text changed. When i have chenget the v-text-field my UI is freezing. How i can add listener to v-text-field without freezing?

Comment: Why not use @change?

Comment: You can use a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) to react when the `$store.state.campaign.MyCost` is changed.

Comment: First of all change `v-model` to `:value`. You are changing state directly with `v-model` and this is considered as BAD practice. Only mutations change state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I think" there're some problems with your code:

- You set your vue-x state directly to v-model `v-model="$store.state.campaign.MyCost"`, it's bad practice
- Your `throttledSave` method seems to not do what you want it to do, it **calls `save` immediately** and return the method `throttle`'s execution (which executes nothing, then return a function without executing it anywhere).
- The `callback` parameter of your `throttle` method actually got **the return value of `this.save`** instead of the function `this.save` itself, so it can't be called like `callback.call();` (call is not a method of undefined)
- I also suspect the logic of your `throttle` method

```js
  save(val) {
    console.log(val); // this doesn't return a function, return undefined
  },

  throttledSave(val) {
    let DELAY = 5000;
    return this.throttle(this.save(val), DELAY); // you called this.save immediately, got undefined
  },

  throttle(callback, limit) {
    console.log("throttle");
    var wait = false;
    return function() { // this function is returned, but will not be executed anywhere
      if (!wait) {
        console.log("throttle");
        callback.call(); // callback is passed in throttledSave is not a function, it's the return result of a function (which this.save's is undefined)
        wait = true;
        setTimeout(function() { // I suspect the logic of your throttle
          wait = false;
        }, limit);
      }
    };
  }
```

**Solution:** What you might want in `throttledSave` is:

```js
computed: {
  DELAY = () => 5000,
},
methods: {
  throttledSave: this.throttle(function(val) { // make sure to write the throttle method correctly 
    this.save(val);
  }, this.DELAY /* or 5000 directly instead */),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use [`lodash`'s throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) instead of writing one from scratch yourself.

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
...
methods: {
  save(val) {
    console.log(val);
  },

  throttledSave: _.throttle(this.save, 5000),

  // or:
  throttledSave: _.throttle(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
  }, 5000),
}
```